# How can I assign the same RBAC role to two different IAM roles to access a cluster in EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, amazon-iam, rbac, amazon-eks

I would like to give a certain team access to the `system:masters` group in RBAC. My team (`AWSReservedSSO_Admin_xxxxxxxxxx` in example below) already has it and it works when I only add that one `rolearn`, but when I apply the configmap below with the additional `rolearn`, users under the `AWSReservedSSO_Dev_xxxxxxxxxx`role still get this error when trying to access the cluster: `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`

(note: we are using AWS SSO, so the IAM roles are assumed):

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/eks-node-group
      groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_Admin_xxxxxxxxxx
      groups:
      - system:masters
      username: admin
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_Dev_xxxxxxxxxx
      groups:
        - system:masters
      username: admin
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Rico. When you sign in with SSO, you are assuming a role in STS. You can verify this by running `aws sts get-caller-identity`.

You werew right that that the username wrong but it didn't solve the whole issue.

Took a long time but my teammate finally found the solution for this [in this guide](https://www.powerupcloud.com/aws-eks-authentication-and-authorization-using-aws-single-signon/)

The problem was the ARN for the IAM Role:

```
rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_Dev_xxxxxxxxxx
```

This part `aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/` needs to be removed from the name. So in the end combined with Rico's suggested username fix:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/eks-node-group
      groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/AWSReservedSSO_Admin_xxxxxxxxxx
      groups:
      - system:masters
      username: admin
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/AWSReservedSSO_Dev_xxxxxxxxxx
      groups:
        - system:masters
      username: admin2
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
```

The issue is finally fixed, and SSO users assuming the role can run `kubectl` commands!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you are assuming the roles ❓ and your configuration looks fine, but the reason could be that you are mapping the same user to two different roles. AWS IAM only allows a user to assume only one role at a time, [basically, as an AWS IAM user, you can't assume multiple IAM roles at the same time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use.html).

You can try with different users and see it works for you.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/eks-node-group
      groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_Admin_xxxxxxxxxx
      groups:
      - system:masters
      username: admin
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_Dev_xxxxxxxxxx
      groups:
        - system:masters
      username: admin2
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
```

The other aspect that you may be missing is the 'Trust Relationship'  in your `arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_Dev_xxxxxxxxxx` role that allows `admin` to assume the role.

[image: image1]

✌️☮️

Comment: Hi Rico, thanks for this solution. You were right that the username was wrong but that wasn't the main issue. I posted the solution in the post. Thank you!